# C# Visual Studio Executable cannot read files within same folder

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2019, desktop-application, user-permissions

Application info:
Visual Studio 2019
.NET 5.0
Windows Form application.

I'm making a App.Config file that will store user specific variables in XML format. The Executable will read the file and pull the information.
I made sure to copy everything from the debug folder to the new folder (C:\Program Files (x86)\Test)

It works on my end but for half of the end users the program cannot read the config file. The program loads but the config file isn't being read.

Is there a security setting I'm missing on the folder itself? I've ran the .exe file as administrator and it still isn't finding the file that are in the same Test folder.

Code in case it matters (I think it's a security issue not code issue):

```
            XDocument xdocument = XDocument.Load("Application.config");
            IEnumerable<XElement> items = xdocument.Root.Elements();
            foreach (var item in items)
            {
                Configs.Add(item.Name.ToString(), item.Value.ToString());
            }

            Logging.WriteToLog("Config File:");
            foreach (string item in Configs.Keys)
            {
                Logging.WriteToLog(item + ": " + Configs[item].ToString());
            }

            if(!ReadBoards())
            {
                return false;
            }

            return true;
```

XML File named Application.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <LogFilePath>C:\Program Files (x86)\Test\Logs\</LogFilePath>
<Email>email@email.com</MondayEmail>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Where in the code you are accessing the file from `C:\Program Files (x86)\Test)`?

Comment: what goes wrong

Comment: the .config, application.exe,  and all DLLs are in the C:\Program Files (x86)\Test.

Comment: Sometimes when you copy files to another machine the files are blocked by Windows security. Right click the file, check that it doesn't have an "unblock" option on the file properties window. Usually config files are read from the same directory first so given you are executing in that directory you'd expect the application to have permissions to the folder it's running from.

Comment: you make the fundamental assumption that the file is in the current dir, what makes you think thats is true. Most apps get installed somewhere and pointed to via a PATH env variable, like `program files`  that will not be the current dir when a user runs it

Comment: I was able to get more information on this. The error the user is seeing is "Access to the path C:\Prgram files (x86)\Test is denied

Comment: Was able to fix it with 1 user by going to the Test folder - Right Click - Properties - Security - Allow - Apply to every user there. Doesn't sound secure but it worked.
This step did not work with the other user though.

Comment: @Meneghini Hi, glad to know you've found the solution to resolve this issue! Please consider accepting it as answer to change its status to Answered. See [can I answer my own question..](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), Just a reminder :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somehow the test folder that was created didn't have the right security permissions and wouldn't accept the permissions when added. The resolution was deleting the test folder and manually creating it and setting up the security.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe in that case, it would be good idea to check the executable directory path runtime by alert(or message box) where executable runs on. So I suggest that you check the executable path runtime before loading application config file.  If then, you might be able to address the issue I think.